# To what extent are visual proofs acceptable

Tags: soft-question, research

In geometry, it seems that visual proofs are much more acceptable than in for example algebra (for good reason). My question is about when visual proofs are sufficient in the context of mathematics research papers. I will give an explicit example to make the question more directed:

> *Theorem*: If we consider the unit circle, in $\mathbb{C}$, i.e. the set
> $$ S=\{z\in\mathbb{C} | |z| = 1\} $$
> As a subspace of the metric $\mathbb{C}$, then the intrinsic metric on $S$ is given by
> \begin{align}
> d_{intr}: S^2 &\to S \\
> (z_1,z_2) &\mapsto \theta
> \end{align}
> Where $\theta$ is the smallest angle between the two numbers in radians.

From a formal point of view, this is quite a bold statement, the intrinsic metric on some connected subspace is not a trivial concept, and to formally prove this theorem, would likely require a decent amount of tedious effort: First you need to prove that there is a path between any two points, and then you need to show that the infimum of all path lengths of paths connecting two particular points agrees with the given expression.

From a less formal point of view, this is just a circle, and the length of an arc is given by the angle that it stretches over, which is the angle between the two numbers. A justification like this could be accompanied for example with a sketch that shows two numbers, and colours the shortest path between them, with the relevant angle drawn in as well. This is clearly not a formal proof, but it is convincing.

My question is, in the context of a research article, is such a justification sufficient for something which is as "apparent" as the above statement, or is there the expectation that even statements like these should be accompanied by a proper proof, or at least a reference?

(I did consider posting this on academia stack exchange instead, but the specific example might not be very effective there, and it is quite relevant to my concern)

Comment: For a research article, you can certainly assume that your audience knows what the usual metrics on $S^1$ are, even without the picture. (Though if it's relevant, you might want to clarify whether your circle has length $1$ or $2\pi$.)

Comment: @anomaly And do you think the same applies to spaces which are less known, but not too complicated either, for example if I wanted to describe the intrinsic metric on the topologist's comb with an added "spine" at the bottom, would it be sufficient to say that one simply takes the horizontal distance between the teeth that the 2 points lie on, and adds the height of both points? It seems obvious, but I am quite unfamiliar with this kind of thing

Comment: It should be clear to the reader that $d(p, q) = |p_1 - q_1| + |p_2 - q_2|$ is a metric on (the underlying set of) the comb space. That particular space is usually metrized as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, though, the point being that it's then path-connected but not locally path-connected. If you're constructing it otherwise, that is something you should tell the reader.

Comment: A fully rigorous proof is needed if you're a math researcher but it's good to include a visual proof too so people see something intuitively.